# UTF-8 to unicode converter for embeded system display

Tags: c, linux, upnp

I have an embedded system that gets UTF-8 encoded data to display via UPNP. The display device has the ability to display characters. I need a way to convert the UTF-8 data I recieve via UPNP to unicode. The display is on a PIC, and it is sent data via a UPNP bridge running linux. Is there a simple way to do the conversion before I send it to the display board in linux?

Comment: What do you think U in UTF-8 stands for?

Comment: UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format—8-bit[1]) is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set.

Comment: So how do you imagine a conversion from an encoding of Unicode characters to Unicode?

Comment: @n.m.: The term Unicode is often used to mean the canonical fixed width Unicode encoding of 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: @JoSo The term Unicode is used (correctly or not) for a whole lot of thing, including UTF-8.

Comment: `the display is on a PIC` -- question is not clear. Do you know what exactly does the display accept? Unicode code points? UCS-2? UCS-4? UTF-16? I find it hard to believe that the display actually speaks unicode code points but the people answering you seem to be making that assumption. Note that the PIC itself does not understand unicode at all and simply treats everything as a bunch of 8 bit values.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I got it converted on the linux upnp renderer, and sent it to the PIC display board via a serial port. The display is using EasyGUI which supports 16 bit unicode. Sorry I was not more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an array of bytes encoded as UFT-8 into an array of Unicode code points:

The trick is to detect various encoding mistakes.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint32_t UnicodePoint;  // Accumulated code point
  uint32_t Min;           // Minimum acceptable codepoint
  int i;                  // Index of char/wchar_t remaining
  bool e;                 // Error flag
} UTF_T;

static bool IsSurrogate(unsigned c) {
  return (c >= 0xD800) && (c <= 0xDFFF);
}

// Return true if more bytes needed to complete codepoint
static bool Put8(UTF_T *U, unsigned ch) {
  ch &= 0xFF;
  if (U->i == 0) {
    if (ch <= 0x7F) {
      U->UnicodePoint = ch;
      return false; /* No more needed */
    } else if (ch <= 0xBF) {
      goto fail;
    } else if (ch <= 0xDF) {
      U->Min = 0x80;
      U->UnicodePoint = ch & 0x1F;
      U->i = 1;
    } else if (ch <= 0xEF) {
      U->Min = 0x800;
      U->UnicodePoint = ch & 0x0F;
      U->i = 2;
    } else if (ch <= 0xF7) {
      U->Min = 0x10000;
      U->UnicodePoint = ch & 0x07;
      U->i = 3;
    } else {
      goto fail;
    }
    return true; /* More needed */
  }
  // If expected continuation character missing ...
  if ((ch & (~0x3F)) != 0x80) {
    goto fail;
  }
  U->UnicodePoint <<= 6;
  U->UnicodePoint |= (ch & 0x3F);
  // If last continuation character ...
  if (--(U->i) == 0) {
    // If codepoint out of range ...
    if ((U->UnicodePoint < U->Min) || (U->UnicodePoint > 0x10FFFF) 
        || IsSurrogate(U->UnicodePoint)) {
      goto fail;
    }
    return false /* No more needed */;
  }
  return true; /* More needed */

  fail:
  U->UnicodePoint = -1;
  U->i = 0;
  U->e = true;
  return false /* No more needed */;
}

/* return 0:OK, else error */
bool ConvertUTF8toUnicodeCodepoints(const char *UTF8, size_t Length, 
    uint32_t *CodePoints, size_t *OutLen) {
  UTF_T U = { 0 };
  *OutLen = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < Length;) {
    while (Put8(&U, UTF8[i++])) {
      // Needed bytes not available?
      if (i >= Length) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (U.e) break;
    CodePoints[(*OutLen)++] = U.UnicodePoint;
  }
  return U.e;
}
```

This is based on some old code, please advise as it may not be up to current standards.
Not the prettiest with `goto` and magic numbers.

What is nice about this approach is rather than `CodePoints[(*OutLen)++] = U.UnicodePoint` for consuming the codepoint, if one wanted to extract UTF16 (BE or LE), one could easily write consumer code for the `UTF_T` block and not need to change to the UTF8 -> codepoint part.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it in the morning and see if it gets me closer.

Comment: Just a note: This code treats the two values in [Surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) as an error. If you need support for them: (1) encountering a high surrogate is an error, (2) when encountering a low surrogate, a high surrogate *must* follow.

Comment: @Jongware Agree that this code encountering _any_ surrogate is an error.  I was following the www.unicode.org [UTF-16 surrogate pair to UTF-8 FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4) which promotes that as an error.  Of course one could amend this code to be more forgiving.  See also [error handling](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen8).

Comment: This code looks incorrect; I don't see anything that keeps it from misinterpreting illegal sequences that look like other characters. If nothing else, it's overly complex.

Comment: @R.. Please provide an illegal sequence to back your assertion.

Comment: @OP Did find and corrected a `U->Min` value that did allow illegal sequence E0 90 80.  Turns outs that bug was corrected before - I pull code a bit too old.  Tested this and passed for legal/illegal 1,2,3 and 4 byte patterns.

Comment: BTW the space of UTF-8 is sufficiently small that you can test all possible inputs. Such testing should be standard practice for any UTF-8 implementation. (Note that you don't need to test all possible 4-byte sequences even; a good decoder should give an error immediately on the first mismatching byte. So the only 4-byte sequences you need to test are ones where the first 3 bytes are a valid prefix.)

Comment: @R.. The space of _valid_ UTF-8 is small, but not the so for _invalid_ input.  An up to 4-byte sequence for testing UTF8 to code point conversion falls short in some cases.  As Jongware suggested above, a UTF8 encoding of a lo/hi pair of surrogates (each taking 3 byte) should result in a valid code point.  Although I (and I think Unicode.com) do not agree that such a 6-byte sequence is valid, it does show that it may take 6 bytes before a UTF-8 to code point conversion may render that response.  We certainly both agree testing is very important.

Comment: @chux: That's not UTF-8; it's CESU-8. Surrogates are not Unicode Scalar Values and thus they can never be encoded by any UTF (UTFs are defined as mappings between Unicode Scalar Values and sequences of code units). In this case, it does not take 6 bytes to determine that the sequence is invalid; it takes only 2 bytes.

Comment: @R.. Suppose a candidate UTF-8 to code point conversion function took the 6 byte input and returned a code point and called it "valid".  We would classify that as a failure in the test, but it took 6 bytes to generate that failure.

Comment: @chux: If we assume that the interface to the decoder allows the caller to pass bytes one at a time and that the test is going to demand the decoder report errors immediately, you would see the failure after submitting just 2 bytes, for example, `ED A0`, without getting an error back. There is never a case where you would have to submit more than 4 bytes, and the only cases where you submit even 4 bytes involve 3 legal prefix bytes followed by a byte not in the range `80` to `BF`.

Comment: @R.. True that if we testing a decoder where 1 byte at a time was provided, 4 bytes would suffice.  If we were testing a decoder like `mbrtowc()` where we passed an array of UTF-8 bytes and it returned code point(s), 6 would be needed to catch the 2 surrogate case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a real operating system and hosted C environment at your disposal, the best approach would be to simply ensure that your program runs in a locale that uses UTF-8 as its encoding and use `mbrtowc` or `mbtowc` to convert UTF-8 sequences to Unicode codepoint values (`wchar_t` is a Unicode codepoint number on Linux and any C implementation that defines `__STDC_ISO_10646__`).

If you do want to skip the system library routines and do UTF-8 decoding yourself, be careful. I once did a casual survey using Google code search and found that somewhere between 1/3 and 2/3 of the UTF-8 code out in the wild was dangerously wrong. Here is a fully correct, fast, and simple implementation I would highly recommend:

http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/

[My implementation in musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/multibyte) is somewhat smaller in binary size and seems to be faster, but it's also a bit harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Unicode manipulation functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) of GLib, a LGPL-licensed utility library. It sounds like [g_utf8_to_ucs4()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-to-ucs4) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think GLib is released under LGPL.  This may have implications for its use in an embedded product so it'd be good to be clear about licensing (and, if you understand it, its implications) in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, GLib is indeed LGPL, I'll add a mention. I don't agree that it's necessary to include more about the implications of the license: A) LGPL-like licenses don't really put any licensing requirements on your application itself. B) There's not a word on shipping a product in the question itself. C) If you are shipping a linux device, you are already doing licensing due diligence for the dozens of other pieces of software you ship: GLib licensing will not be a massive surprise among those...

Comment: Point taken about the due diligence required to ship a linux device.  I think there are some implications to using LGPL though...  LGPL licenses require that the end-user has the ability to upgrade the LGPL'd part of an application, even if you don't provide a means to upgrade the rest of the app.  Some embedded devices may not include any means to upgrade any software

Comment: LGPL doesn't (AFAIK) require being able to upgrade it in-place on the device, just providing the proper dynamic linked executable or object files so that a user can relink it against a modified library (how to get that onto the device is still the user's problem). This is a less stringent requirement than the GPL under which the kernel is licensed (and under which Busybox, which you're probably also using, is licensed).